# Why aren't instructions' adresses consecutive in machine code?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, machine-code

I just compiled a CPP source code into an object `.o` file, and the first couple of lines are like the following:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_Z8mainLoopv>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4:   55                      push   %rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   8:   41 55                   push   %r13
   a:   41 54                   push   %r12
   c:   53                      push   %rbx
   d:   48 81 ec 88 00 00 00    sub    $0x88,%rsp
  14:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
```

I am assuming the first column is the adress of the instructions, am I right? If so, why aren't they consecutive? Something like this:

```
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   1:   55                      push   %rbp
   2:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   3:   41 55                   push   %r13
   4:   41 54                   push   %r12
   5:   53                      push   %rbx
   6:   48 81 ec 88 00 00 00    sub    $0x88,%rsp
   7:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
```

Comment: Some instructions occupy several bytes. Notice the different row lengths.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Simpler than I thought haha thanks

Comment: Note that data is similar: mulit byte data is referred to by lowest address among its bytes;  consecutive mulit byte elements in an array will appear to skip addreses, for example.

Comment: they are sequential.  start at 0 then each byte in that instruction is 1,2,3, then 4 is next, then 5,6,7, then 8 and so on.

Comment: *Ps.: Why you guys downvoting this?* - I didn't downvote, but I assume the downvotes are from people who thought the answer was completely obvious given a basic understanding of bytes and addresses.  It was probably even obvious to you once you read the answer, but that doesn't necessarily make it a bad SO question.  You did format it well, and clearly explain exactly what you're wondering about so it was possible to answer it easily, without a lot of guesswork to figure out what misconception it was based on.  If this ever comes up again, now we have a canonical Q&A for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first column is the address of the instruction.

Because x86_64 instructions aren't the same length (like ARM64 for example), the value difference varies. The second column show the bytes of each instructions. Notice that they have different lengths.

Comment: Yes, but the addresses in a `.o` are calculated starting at 0 for the first instruction in the *file*, not the function.  Linkers don't really know about functions, just symbol addresses and relocation entries.  (i.e. the infrastructure needed to compile high-level code with functions into linkable object files).  In a linked executable, addresses would start from some base address.  (In a PIE, probably `0x1000`, or for a non-PIE often `0x401000` on Linux, IIRC.)

Comment: Note that ARM64 is not a fixed-length instruction set either as SVE instructions come with prefixes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ahh yeah, my bad. I was trying to make a offset base out of the blue to explain...

Comment: @fuz What? I've never seen an ARM64 instruction that is longer than 4 bytes. I'm talking about ARMv8 64bit

Comment: @ntrung03 Basically, with SVE there are prefix instructions that modify the following instruction.  These can be implemented as separate instructions, but they are meant to be decoded and implemented as 8 byte long instructions.  It's similar to how `IT` behaves as a prefix in Thumb mode when only one instruction is affected.  ARM has deprecated most other uses of `IT` so it can be thought of as a prefix in a variable length instruction set.

Comment: @ntrung03: You can [edit] your answer to correct that minor point.  That's what comments are for.

Comment: @fuz, section A1.3.2 of the ARMv8 ARM (DDI 0487G.a) states that `AArch64 state supports only a single instruction set, called A64. This is a fixed-length instruction
set that uses 32-bit instruction encodings.`

Comment: @fuz Do you have a source for that? Or even just an example of such "prefixes"? Your claim seems to contradict everything the ARMv8 Reference Manual has to say about this.

Comment: @Siguza See the [`MOVPRFX` instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-06/SVE-Instructions/MOVPRFX--unpredicated---Move-prefix--unpredicated--).  The SVE section in the ARM Architecture Reference Manual provides further details on how it behaves like a prefix.

Comment: @Siguza: It may be a sort of semantic argument.  I guess the idea is that you do `MOVPRFX z0, z1 ; SDIV z0, z2` to get the effect of `SDIV z0, z1, z2`.  You could think of the two as a single 8-byte instruction.  Or you could think of `MOVPRFX` as an independent instruction which simply has the effect of `MOV z0, z1`, but with the additional requirement that the following instruction must be one of a certain set, and with the "hint" that the machine may be able to fuse the two.

Comment: @Siguza: So if you still want to think that every instruction is 4 bytes, you just have to resign yourself to the possibility that some instructions' behavior depends on which instruction follows them in sequence (here, the behavior of `MOVPRFX` may be either `MOV` or `UNPREDICTABLE`).

Comment: I was wondering why they would introduce this, instead of just encouraging core designers to make MOV execute in zero cycles at register renaming, as some machines can do.  Then programmers could just write `MOV z0, z1 ; SDIV z0, z2` as usual, and be eligible for the same performance gain. But it seems that zero-cycle move is [patented by Apple](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130275720A1/), so maybe this was an attempt to design around that patent?  Juts a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Each instruction can take more than one bytes of space. Here, the first instruction takes four bytes of space(`f3 0f 1e fa`) so the next instruction starts at byte 4.